Is there a method to sequentially label a collection of geographical points that follow a route with a changing direction?
I have a collection of geographical points (xy coordinates) looking like this:

Collectively they follow a route with a changing direction. I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the order of these points (then label them with that order). Sort of like this:

(the blue arrow represents the overall direction of the route)
Since the direction of the route keeps changing, it is not so simple to just order by north-south or east-west (i.e. order by the y coordinate or x coordinate respectively). The change in direction needs to be accounted for. All I have thought of is treating the xy points as points on a graph, calculating a line of best fit, then using the changing gradient to find the direction, then using that value to order the points. But not sure if that is possible, or if there are better methods (if any).

This is just speculation and would require some coding but it it worth an investigation.  Generate Theissen polygons for your points.  Use the script linked below to attribute adjacent polygons with increasing count values starting with point 1.  Add a new attribute.  Select  all of the adjacent polygons with values of twos.  Use the new attribute to increment and assign all of the adjacent twos with increasing values, repeat with the threes, fours...  https://github.com/LummiGIS/Attribute-adjacent-geometries-with-increasing-count-values

I like the centreline idea. But don't fully understand "Order the points by their distance along the line" - would you mind explaining it a little more?

From the points in your 2nd screenshot: based on what can you say the "correct" order is 1-2-3 etc. and not, say, from point labeled 1 to point 4-3-5-6-2-8-7-9 etc. This order would make completely sense to me. So I have no idea what the order of the points should represent.

Create a networkx graph, find shortest path between the two ends and create a line of the path. For each point calculate its location along the line, sort the points by the distance and create a label column.
import geopandas as gpd
import networkx as nx
import shapely
from itertools import combinations

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/random_route_points.shp") #A point dataframe with an id field with unique value for each point
# print(df.head(3).to_string(index=False))
#  id                  geometry
#   1 POINT (20.13032 64.06364)
#   2 POINT (20.18135 64.08505)
#   3 POINT (20.13782 64.05535)

#Reproject to a projected coordinate system, to get distances in meters
df.to_crs(crs=df.estimate_utm_crs(), inplace=True)
# print(df.head(3).to_string(index=False))
#  id                       geometry
#   1 POINT (457559.735 7104395.093)
#   2 POINT (460080.501 7106747.820)
#   3 POINT (457913.538 7103467.263)
ax = df.plot(color="red", markersize=4)


#Build a graph. Create a line connecting all point pairs within a distance lower than max_distance
G = nx.Graph()
max_distance=700 #Adjust this. You dont want to connect points across the line bends
pointlist = []
for point1, point2 in combinations(zip(df["id"], df["geometry"]), 2):
    distance = point1[1].distance(point2[1])
    if distance<=max_distance:
        G.add_edge(point1[0], point2[0], weight=distance)
nx.draw(G, node_size=10, node_color="red", edge_color="gray")


#Calculate shortest path from the end points
shortest_path = nx.dijkstra_path(G, source=97, target=84, weight=distance) #84 and 97 are the ids of the end points, you need to manually specify them.
# print(shortest_path[:5])
# [84, 99, 1, 75, 45] #The shortest path starts at point with id 84, then 99, 1, 75, 45, ...

#Create a line from the path
id_to_geometry = dict(zip(df["id"], df["geometry"])) #Create a dictionary with the point ids as keys and the point geometries as values
# {1: <POINT (457559.735 7104395.093)>,
#  2: <POINT (460080.501 7106747.82)>,
#  3: <POINT (457913.538 7103467.263)>,
#  ...}

shortest_line = shapely.LineString([id_to_geometry[i] for i in shortest_path])
gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[shortest_line], crs=df.crs).plot(ax=ax, color="blue")


#Find the distance along the line for each point. 
df["dist_along_line"] = df.apply(lambda x: shortest_line.line_locate_point(x.geometry, normalized=True), axis=1)
# print(df.head(3).to_string(index=False))
#  id                       geometry  dist_along_line
#   1 POINT (457559.735 7104395.093)         0.108792
#   2 POINT (460080.501 7106747.820)         0.392066
#   3 POINT (457913.538 7103467.263)         0.016893

#Sort the point from shortest to longest distance, eg. from the start to the end of the line
df = df.sort_values(by="dist_along_line", ascending=True)
# print(df.head(3).to_string(index=False))
#  id                       geometry  dist_along_line
#  84 POINT (457855.847 7103191.487)         0.000000
#   3 POINT (457913.538 7103467.263)         0.016893
# 124 POINT (458003.225 7103797.476)         0.036216


#Create a label column
df["label"] = range(1, df.shape[0]+1)
# print(df.head(3).to_string(index=False))
#  id                       geometry  dist_along_line  label
#  84 POINT (457855.847 7103191.487)         0.000000      1
#   3 POINT (457913.538 7103467.263)         0.016893      2
# 124 POINT (458003.225 7103797.476)         0.036216      3

df.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/seq_labeled_points.gpkg")



Basic idea: Create a concave hull, get the central axis of it and calculate for each point the distance along this line from the start-point to the closest point on the linestring. See details and screenshot of path connecting the points below.
Initial points (blue), concave hull (orange), central axis (red), closest point of each blue point on the red line (white dot) and points labeled with the distance along the red linestring of their white corresponding point; see the dynamically created label on the upper right side (highlighted in yellow):


Create a concave hull around the ponints (e.g. with treshold 0.1 and and option allow holes disabled).

Create the central axis of the hull, e.g. using PostGIS with the query:
select st_approximatemedialaxis(hull.geom)
from "Concave hull" as hull


Run shortest path from the start to the endpoint (this is because the line segments of the central axis are not properly ordered and go in different directions).

Order the points based on line_locate_point() function (distance along the line of each point's closest point on the linestring) and add @id of each point (to address cases where two points have the same distance). Use this expression:
 array_find(
     array_sort(
         array_agg (
             line_locate_point(
                 geometry (get_feature_by_id ('Shortest path',1)),
                 $geometry
             ) + @id/1000
         )
     ),
     line_locate_point(
         geometry (get_feature_by_id ('Shortest path',1)),
         $geometry
     ) + @id/1000
 )



Path connecting the points:

Slightly different result with smaller Threshold for concave hull:

Same line, simplified and smoothed:

